# Get the annotation on method from the instance that the method created

Tags: java, spring

Here is an example

```
@Target({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.PARAMETER, ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Qualifier
public @interface Annotation {
   
}

@Configuration
public class Configuration {
  
   @Bean
   @Annotation
   public Test getTest() {
       return new Test();
   }
}

public class Test() {
   public void test() {
       // how can get the annotation `@Annotation` here?
   }
}
```

Here is what I have tried `getClass().getAnnotations()` but this returns empty array. I can see why since `getClass()` return Test.class which does not have the annotation. How can I get the method that creates this instance and then get the annotation?

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on what you're trying to achieve? Usually, classes annotated with `@Configuration` are considered spring configuration classes. They're processed by spring itself and it "recognizes" only those annotations that it supports.... If you need to define a functionality - you can place it on the bean itself (`Test` in this case) then you can define a bean post processor to read the annotation and alter the default behaviour...

Answer (score 2):

You could, in theory, inspect the current Thread stack to determine the name of your caller, then look up the class definition, locate the method, and read its annotations:

```
    var t = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[2];
    var className = t.getClassName();
    Class<?> clazz;
    try {
        clazz = Test.class.getClassLoader().loadClass(className);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Caller was loaded by a different ClassLoader :-(");
    }
    for (var method : clazz.getDeclaredMethods()) {
        if (method.getName().equals(t.getMethodName())) {
            return method.getAnnotation(YourAnnotation.class).value();
        }
    }
    throw new RuntimeException("Method not found - I might have found the wrong class definition");
```

However:

- inspecting the stack is rather slow, in particular if the stack is deep
- inspecting the stack is brittle with respect to refactorings (people don't expect that factoring out code into a utility method will change behaviour)
- the compiler can not check that the caller provides the required annotation
- this only works reliably if all code is loaded by the same `ClassLoader`
- this can not distinguish overloaded methods

This is therefore a rather brittle hack. Are you sure that there is no better option? For instance, requiring the caller to pass the value as a method parameter would have none of these shortcomings ...

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ConfigurableListableBeanFactory` to get metadata about any Bean by name. Use [BeanNameAware](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/BeanNameAware.html) interface to retrieve Bean name.

```java
@Target({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.PARAMETER, ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Qualifier
public @interface CustomAnnotation {

}

@org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
public static class ContextConfiguration {
    @Bean(name = "TEST")
    @CustomAnnotation
    public TestObject getTest() {
        return new TestObject();
    }
}

public class TestObject implements BeanNameAware {
    private String beanName;

    @Autowired
    ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory;

    @Override
    public void setBeanName(String name) {
        this.beanName = name;
    }

    public void test() {
        CustomAnnotation customAnnotation = (CustomAnnotation) getBeanAnnotation(beanName, CustomAnnotation.class);
    }

    private Annotation getBeanAnnotation(String beanName, java.lang.Class<? extends Annotation> clazz) {
        Annotation annotation = null;
        BeanDefinition beanDefinition = beanFactory.getBeanDefinition(beanName);

        if( beanDefinition != null && beanDefinition.getSource() instanceof StandardMethodMetadata) {
            StandardMethodMetadata metadata = (StandardMethodMetadata) beanDefinition.getSource();
            annotation = Arrays.stream(metadata.getIntrospectedMethod().getDeclaredAnnotations()).filter(annot -> annot.annotationType().equals(clazz)).findFirst().orElse(null);
        }

        return annotation;
    }

}
```